# Entity Framework ICollections in database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am using database implementation example from [signalR tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections) to find connectionId of connected users.

Here's the code for models:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
}

public class Connection
{
    public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
    public bool Connected { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use database-first model because some of the tables are already implemented and populated. I am new to Entity Framework and having a hard time understanding how user table will be represented in database?

User Table
ColumnName DataType AllowNulls
___________________________
id bigint      (auto incrementing PK)
UserName  varchar(20)
Connection  ???

Answer (score 0):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

```
When right-clicking on a C# project, the following context menu functions are supported:

    Reverse Engineer Code First - Generates POCO classes, derived DbContext and Code First mapping for an existing database.
```

You can learn more about how things work by using this "reverse engineer" tool......than most ways, IMHO.

Again, reverse engineer it , because you're probably more familiar with your db/ddl than the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I have models for all tables in my database implemented and working. Now I am adding these two tables: User and Connection in DB and trying to understand how ICollection of Connection table would be represented as a a column?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using database-first, it's up to you how it will be represented in the database; you write the database first, then you map it to your .NET types. If you're using code-first, and want to see what the generated schema would look like, the easiest way to do that would be to run it.